# How to disable smoothing pose estimation landmarks in mediapipe (Unity plugin)?

Tags: tensorflow, mediapipe

I integrated mediapipe in my Unity project using the [plugin by homuler](https://github.com/homuler/MediaPipeUnityPlugin). Unfortunately, setting `smoothLandmarks = true` for the pose estimation ([PoseTrackingGraph.cs](https://github.com/homuler/MediaPipeUnityPlugin/blob/master/Assets/Mediapipe/Samples/Scenes/Pose%20Tracking/PoseTrackingGraph.cs)) does not have an effect.

```
private SidePacket BuildSidePacket(ImageSource imageSource)
{
    var sidePacket = new SidePacket();

    SetImageTransformationOptions(sidePacket, imageSource);
    sidePacket.Emplace("model_complexity", new IntPacket((int)modelComplexity));
    sidePacket.Emplace("smooth_landmarks", new BoolPacket(smoothLandmarks));

    return sidePacket;
}
```

So I tried to find hints in the [official implementation](https://github.com/google/mediapipe) and directly found matches in the example of the [pose_landmark_cpu.pbtxt](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/e6c19885c6d3c6f410c730952aeed2852790d306/mediapipe/modules/pose_landmark/pose_landmark_cpu.pbtxt#L21)

```
# EXAMPLE:
#   node {
#     calculator: "PoseLandmarkCpu"
#     input_side_packet: "MODEL_COMPLEXITY:model_complexity"
#     input_side_packet: "SMOOTH_LANDMARKS:smooth_landmarks"
#     input_side_packet: "ENABLE_SEGMENTATION:enable_segmentation"
#     input_side_packet: "SMOOTH_SEGMENTATION:smooth_segmentation"
#     input_side_packet: "USE_PREV_LANDMARKS:use_prev_landmarks"
#     input_stream: "IMAGE:image"
#     output_stream: "LANDMARKS:pose_landmarks"
#     output_stream: "SEGMENTATION_MASK:segmentation_mask"
#   }
```

and tried to add `input_side_packet: "SMOOTH_LANDMARKS:smooth_landmarks` to [pose_tracking_cpu.txt](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/graphs/pose_tracking/pose_tracking_cpu.pbtxt) used the by the unity plugin. I know this is a different file, but I just tried to eliminate this option. As expected, this did not work.

So I wonder if you have an idea how I can disable smoothing landmarks for pose estimation?
Maybe you can give me a hint where I can change the c++ directly and rebuild the library afterwards.

Thank you in advance!